# What is the best conditional generative model? And any tips for implementation?

Tags: deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I'm working on generative models to generate some samples for my research.
For some reason, I had to disentangle the latent space, so I tried to apply the ideas of infoGAN and conditional GAN to various architecture.

I thought it was easy but, somehow, the model gave me poor results. Even the same architecture that gives good results without conditions, whenever the conditions are added, it becomes difficult to train.

So, I wonder what is the best conditional architecture and someone can give tips for helping with my models? Some details are below:

Images:

[Generated samples with original DCGAN (non-conditional, good)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Diq.png)

[Generated samples with conditional DCGAN (fail)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2tVl.png)

[Generated samples with conditional WGAN-GP (poor)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT4BV.png)

Codes:

Libraries

```
from functools import partial
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Sequential, Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D, AveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Reshape, Flatten, Concatenate, BatchNormalization, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ReLU, LeakyReLU
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm
from utils import *
import time
import os
```

Model

```
class cWGAN4Rank2(object):
    def __init__(self, z_dim=1, batch_size=64, gen_lr=1e-4, disc_lr=6e-5, lam=10., n_critic=5):
        self.lam = lam
        self.n_critic = n_critic
        # Dataset
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        dataset, num_samples = load_rank2_dataset(False)
        self.dataset = dataset.shuffle(num_samples).batch(batch_size)
        elem_spec = dataset.element_spec
        # Data shapes and dimensions
        self.image_size = elem_spec[0].shape[0]
        self.num_channel = elem_spec[0].shape[2]
        self.image_shape = (self.image_size, self.image_size, self.num_channel)
        self.z_dim = z_dim
        # Models
        self.D = self.build_discriminator(32, 5)
        self.G = self.build_generator(34, 5)
        self.I = keras.models.load_model('/data/inception4rank2.h5')
        c = 0
        for w in self.D.get_weights():
            c += w.size
        print(c)
        c = 0
        for w in self.G.get_weights():
            c += w.size
        print(c)
        # Optimizers
        self.D_opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(disc_lr, .5, .9)
        self.G_opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(gen_lr, .5, .9)
        # Test noise
        self.num_ex = 64
        z = tf.random.uniform(shape=(self.num_ex, self.z_dim), minval=-1, maxval=1)
        c = tf.reshape(tf.constant(np.linspace(0,1,self.num_ex, dtype='float32')), (self.num_ex,1))
        self.seed = tf.concat([z,c], axis=1)
        # Records
        self.epoch = 0
        self.step = 0
        self.steps = []
        self.steps_per_epoch = []
        self.D_loss_per_step = []
        self.D_loss_per_epoch = []
        self.G_loss_per_step = []
        self.G_loss_per_epoch = []
        self.FID_per_step = []
        self.FID_per_epoch = []

    def build_discriminator(self, filters, kernel_size):
        c = Input(shape=(1,))
        t = Dense(32*32)(c)
        t = Reshape((32,32,1))(t)
        t = Activation(tf.nn.leaky_relu)(BatchNormalization()(t))

        x = Input(shape=self.image_shape, name='image_input') # 32x32x1
        y = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding='same')(x)
        y = Activation(tf.nn.leaky_relu)(BatchNormalization()(y))
        y = Concatenate()([y,t])
        y = Conv2D(2*filters, kernel_size, strides=(2,2), padding='same')(y) # 16x16xn
        y = Activation(tf.nn.leaky_relu)(BatchNormalization()(y))
        y = Conv2D(4*filters, kernel_size, strides=(2,2), padding='same')(y) # 8x8xn
        y = Activation(tf.nn.leaky_relu)(BatchNormalization()(y))
        z = Dense(1)(Flatten()(y))
        return Model([x,c], z)

    def build_generator(self, filters, kernel_size):
        x = Input(shape=(self.z_dim+1,))
        y = Reshape((8,8,filters))(Dense(8*8*filters)(x)) # 8x8xn
        y = Activation(tf.nn.relu)(BatchNormalization()(y))
        y = Conv2DTranspose(2*filters, kernel_size, strides=(2,2), padding='same')(y) # 16x16xn
        y = Activation(tf.nn.relu)(BatchNormalization()(y))
        y = Conv2DTranspose(4*filters, kernel_size, strides=(2,2), padding='same')(y) # 32x32xn
        y = Activation(tf.nn.relu)(BatchNormalization()(y))
        z = Conv2D(1, kernel_size, padding='same', activation='tanh')(y)
        return Model(x, z)

    def train(self, num_epochs):
        for e in range(num_epochs):
            self.epoch += 1
            t_epoch = time.time()
            for batch in self.dataset:
                self.step += 1
                for _ in range(self.n_critic):
                    D_loss = self.train_discriminator(batch)
                self.D_loss_per_step.append(D_loss.numpy())
                G_loss = self.train_generator()
                self.G_loss_per_step.append(G_loss.numpy())

                self.steps.append(self.step)
            self.steps_per_epoch.append(self.step)
            self.D_loss_per_epoch.append(D_loss)
            self.G_loss_per_epoch.append(G_loss)
            FID = self.fid_eval(batch)
            self.FID_per_epoch.append(FID)

            if (e+1) % 10 == 0:
                display.clear_output(True)
                self.visualization()

            print('[{: 3d}/{: 3d}]epoch, D_loss= {:.4e}, G_loss= {:.4e}, time= {:.2f} sec'.format(e+1, num_epochs, D_loss, G_loss, time.time()-t_epoch))

    @tf.function
    def train_discriminator(self, batch):
        X_real = 2 * batch[0] - 1
        c_real = tf.reduce_mean(batch[0], axis=(1,2))
        z = tf.random.uniform(shape=(self.batch_size, self.z_dim), minval=-1, maxval=1)
        c_fake = tf.random.uniform(shape=(self.batch_size,1))
        h = tf.concat([z, c_fake], axis=1)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            X_fake = self.G(h, training=True)
            y_fake = self.D((X_fake,c_fake), training=True)
            y_real = self.D((X_real,c_real), training=True)
            real_loss = tf.reduce_mean(y_real)
            fake_loss = tf.reduce_mean(y_fake)
            D_loss = fake_loss - real_loss
            gp = self.gradient_penalty(partial(self.D, training=True), X_real, X_fake, c_real, c_fake)
            loss = D_loss + self.lam * gp
        grad = tape.gradient(loss, self.D.trainable_variables)
        self.D_opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, self.D.trainable_variables))
        return D_loss

    @tf.function
    def train_generator(self):
        z = tf.random.uniform(shape=(self.batch_size, self.z_dim), minval=-1, maxval=1)
        c_fake = tf.random.uniform(shape=(self.batch_size,1))
        h = tf.concat([z, c_fake], axis=1)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            X_fake = self.G(h, training=True)
            y_fake = self.D((X_fake,c_fake), training=True)
            fake_loss = tf.reduce_mean(y_fake)
            #vol_loss = .5 * tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.reduce_mean((X_fake+1)/2, axis=(1,2)) - c_fake))
            loss = -fake_loss# + vol_loss
        grad = tape.gradient(loss, self.G.trainable_variables)
        self.G_opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, self.G.trainable_variables))
        return loss

    @tf.function
    def gradient_penalty(self, f, X_real, X_fake, c_real, c_fake):
        alpha = tf.random.uniform((self.batch_size, 1, 1, 1))
        beta = tf.reshape(alpha, (-1,1))
        inter = (alpha * X_real + (1 - alpha) * X_fake, beta * c_real + (1 - beta) * c_fake)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            tape.watch(inter)
            pred = f(inter)
        grad = tape.gradient(pred, inter)
        slopes = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(grad[0]), axis=(1,2,3)) + tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(grad[1]), axis=1))
        return tf.reduce_mean((slopes - 1.)**2)

    def fid_eval(self,batch):
        X_real = 2 * batch[0] - 1
        z = tf.random.uniform(shape=(self.batch_size, self.z_dim), minval=-1, maxval=1)
        c_fake = tf.random.uniform(shape=(self.batch_size,1))
        h = tf.concat([z, c_fake], axis=1)
        X_fake = (self.G(h, training=False) + 1) / 2
        a_real = self.I(X_real, training=False)
        a_fake = self.I(X_fake, training=False)
        mu_real, sig_real = tf.reduce_mean(a_real, axis=0), np.cov(a_real, rowvar=False)
        mu_fake, sig_fake = tf.reduce_mean(a_fake, axis=0), np.cov(a_fake, rowvar=False)
        ssdiff = np.sum((mu_real - mu_fake)**2)
        covmean = sqrtm(sig_real.dot(sig_fake))
        if np.iscomplexobj(covmean):
            covmean = covmean.real
        return ssdiff + np.trace(sig_real + sig_fake - 2.0 * covmean)

    def visualization(self):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(20,5))
        X_test = self.G(self.seed, training=False)
        nrow = int(np.floor(np.sqrt(self.num_ex)))
        ncol = int(np.ceil(self.num_ex / nrow))
        X_tile = np.zeros(shape=((self.image_size+2)*nrow,(self.image_size+2)*ncol))
        for row in range(nrow):
            for col in range(ncol):
                ind = ncol * row + col
                irow, icol = np.meshgrid(np.arange(self.image_size+2) + row*(self.image_size+2),
                                         np.arange(self.image_size+2) + col*(self.image_size+2))

                try:
                    X_tile[irow,icol] = tf.pad(X_test[ind,:,:,0],[[1,1],[1,1]])
                except:
                    None
        ax[0].imshow(1-X_tile, cmap='gray')
        ax[1].plot(self.steps, self.D_loss_per_step, label='discriminator')
        ax[1].plot(self.steps, self.G_loss_per_step, label='generator')
        ax[1].legend()
        ax[2].plot(self.steps_per_epoch, self.FID_per_epoch, label='FID')
        ax[2].legend()
        plt.show()
```